# File in directory can't be opened because of a hashtag

Tags: php, hashtag

I am currently building something like a cloud.
So the users can upload stuff and then of course download it again.
Right now most of it works fine, but I noticed that there is a problem with files which contain a "#" in their name.

For example the file Name could be: "Double Color #2.jpg"

With the variable "$placeoffile" I want to link directly to the file.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
        if (is_dir($dir)){
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                    if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                        $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        $size = filesize($dir.$file);
                        $placeoffile = $dir.$file;
                        echo("
                        <td><a href='$placeoffile'>filename: $file </a></td>
                        <td>$extension</td>
                        <td>$size</td>
                        <td>$placeoffile</td>
                        <tr>");
                    }
                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I get the error "Double Color was not found on this server." so somehow everything after the hashtag has been deleted from the search and therefore it obviously didn't find it.

Tried htmlspecialchars and preg but I dont want to rename the files of the users or show a error message to them if they upload a file with a weird name.
I feel like there is an easy solution to this, but I just don't see it.
Any help? Cheers :)

Comment: After doing what do you get the error `"Double Color was not found on this server."`

Comment: When I open the link. Usually it shows me the picture or data but if there is a hashtag in the name, it only shows the error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to escape the '#' as it is a special character.  try replacing the # with `\#`

Comment: Problem being that I never know which name the file will have because the user uploads it himself. Hmm

Comment: Then you'll need to add string checking functionality to validate the user input and modify it as necessary.  This will become a much larger problem than just issues with `#`, unless you do implement string validation.  It can, in fact, present security hazards.